# how to dynamically modify the attribute in a query using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using `sqlalchemy` and i wonder if its possible to dynamically modify an attribute of a class while doing a query

```
if school == "abc":
         school_data = (
             meta.session.query(
                 model.School.name, <=== HERE
...
```

i want to be able to dynamically change `.name.` to another field, is it possible with python and sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `getattr` :

```python
if school == "abc":
   attr = "name"
else:
   attr = "id"

school_data = meta.session.query(getattr(model.School, attr) ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you need, but you can do

```
c = "name"
getattr(table.c, c)
```

this gets a column from a table, named c - which can be any string. I am quite sure you can adapt this to model.School